# Is there a UI for editing helm charts and storing them?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

There are helm repositories which can store helm charts. There are UIs of ArgoCD, Kubeapps which let us live edit the helm charts. But they don't store the edited helm chart. I want to know if there is a UI for editing and storing the helm charts back in a helm repository. I've searched around the net and haven't found one yet.

Comment: https://ahoyhelm.org/ is a simple UI, and I think it lets you edit charts, but I haven't tried that. Maybe you want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone comes back to this question, there's a new GUI plugin for Helm called Helm-Dashboard. Check it out: https://github.com/komodorio/helm-dashboard

Comment: I wrote a small tool to edit helm charts, it runs in docker containers, and you just mount the helm chart and then you can edit it with a split screen editor in your browser. https://github.com/tobiashochguertel/th-helm-playground-frontend

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools for that.  Here is an example https://monokle.kubeshop.io/